# Deciding the 'this' context in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I understand the context of this in a function is decided by the call site or call stack . In below example , even though the call to bar() is made from foo(), Why 'this' inside bar() is not pointing to foo()?

```
function bar(){
  console.log(this);
 }

function foo()
{
 bar();
}

foo();
```

Comment: `this` in your example is the global window unless you use `strict`

Comment: @mplungjan: In loose mode. In strict mode it's `undefined`.

Comment: That's because `this` **is not** determined by the call stack. Where did you get that from? `this` is set by using `o.method(arg1, arg2, ...);` syntax *or* by explicitely calling `method.call(...)` *or* `method.apply(...)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification. I never used strict.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work